# Migrating deprecated app (mysql_* to mysqli): Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm updating an app that was deprecated `(mysql_*)` using mysqli and I'm having troubles with this query:

```
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO login (user, password, date) 
        VALUES ('$user', '$password', CURDATE())", $con) or die ("Error query.");
```

According to the oficial documentation, the code should be:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO login (user, password, date) 
        VALUES ('$user', '$password', CURDATE())") or die ("Error query.");
```

But that throws the following:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string
```

I've checked if I'm connecting with mysqli and not with mysql because that error happened to me before and was caused because I was querying with `mysql` and connecting with `mysqli`. Another option is just saving the query into a variable and then working around it.

My connection.php:

```
define('DB_SERVER','myserver');
define('DB_NAME','mydbname');
define('DB_USER','myuser');
define('DB_PASS','myDBPass');
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
mysqli_select_db($con,DB_NAME);
```

Comment: Try replacing:
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
    mysqli_select_db($con,DB_NAME);
with
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

And add for Debugging:
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

Comment: The first param in mysqli_query must be $con. Please check type of variables `$user` and `$password`. If `$user` and `$password` is string, sure you could run as well

Comment: Variables are correct because my login is working, only the signup query fails.

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing

```
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
mysqli_select_db($con,DB_NAME);
```

to

```
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
```

Then use mysqli_select_db if you want to swap Databases.

Answer (score 0):

Let see the bellow code is running well,

```
define('DB_SERVER','127.0.0.1');
define('DB_NAME','test');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS','');
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
mysqli_select_db($con,DB_NAME);

$name = 'Vu Tuan Anh'
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO sample (name, date) 
    VALUES ('$name', CURDATE())") or die ("Error query.");
```

But if i make some mistake, `$name` => get value from `$con` like `$name = $con`

=> error: `Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string`

But if i make other mistake, `$name` => is array like `$name= array('abc')`

=> error: `Array to string conversion in testdb.php on line 12`

So, just check your code by var_dump

```
$query = "INSERT INTO login (user, password, date) VALUES ('$user', '$password', CURDATE())";
var_dump($query);
mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("error query");
```